# Session Variable Checker PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, authentication, session-variables

I'm trying to create a session variable check for each of my pages on my website.  The below code is close but I just don't know if I've constructed the If, elseif and else statements correctly.  Thanks!

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['administrator'] == 'YES'){
    session_write_close();
    echo "You are logged in & you are an administrator!";
    exit();
}   elseif (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        session_write_close();
        echo "You are logged in BUT you are NOT an administrator!";
        exit();
    }   else {
    session_write_close();
    echo "You are NOT logged in!";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tested it? What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: I'm not question what the sure is here.

Comment: what problem you have faced with this code.....

Comment: The first case works but the other two cases don't return any results.  In other words if I login with admin then it returns the proper first echo.  If I log in with a normal (non-admin) account it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: @r6danl99 that's wrong. The code is functionally OK.

Comment: Sorry.  My error was in my login check.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work as you expect. However, you could write it like below instead - it just saves you writing the `id` check twice.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
     if($_SESSION['administrator'] == 'YES')
     {
         // is admin
     }
     else
     {
         // logged in but not admin
     }
}
else
{
    // not logged in
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me in drunkmen's terms how this is better than whatever it is OP has?

Comment: @PeeHaa as mentioned, the difference is you don't write `isset($_SESSION['id'])` twice. There doesn't seem any point in duplicating that.

Comment: I will select this as an answer since it helped me clean up my code.  Thanks!